# Can lab refuse to release test results to ordering physician until getting paid?

Tags: united-states, medical, billing

My doctor ordered a genetic testing to a lab in New Jersey which is out-of network for my insurance. The lab didn't submit a claim to my insurance, instead directly sent me a bill and tell me that they won't release my test results to the doctor's office until I pay them in full. Is this even legal in US for a CLIA certified lab to not release results to the ordering physician until getting paid? I'm not talking about releasing to patient, that's already addressed by the new rule.

Comment: Probably. Considering a full answer with authority but that would take a while.